# AWS video-on-demand-on-aws template portrait problems - MediaCoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, rotation

I have deployed the video-on-demand-on-aws template and modified it a bit - removing DASH and MP4 output, and removing some of the HLS low-res outputs.

Initially videos recorded by iPhone in portrait were transcoded to landscape by the MediaConvert.
Starting from 28 Feb, the MediaConvert supports rotation, but ignores the Rotation metadata.

I had to modify the “encode” Lambda function – by adding `“Rotate”: “90”` to the `“VideoSelector”` section, updating the aws-sdk version (the deployed solution used an old version not supporting the Rotate tag), repackaging and uploading the zip.

Now MediaConvert doesn’t ignore the rotation metadata (but it doesn’t pass it through), but it rotates the video – but not as expected!

I have this two problems:

1. The video is rotated but not correctly – the portrait video if fitted to the landscape (1280x720) frame with a lot of black space on the sides, instead of “REAL” rotation (1280x720 with rotation metadata -> 720x1280 without rotation tag). Is there a way to get a “REAL” rotation, like flip the whole video by 90 degrees
2. The transcoded HLS segments (I need only the HLS output, DASH and MP4 outputs are deleted) are buggy – they freeze – for example a 20 second video tends to have 1-3 freezes – verified by downloading the .TS files and playing them VLC, Potplayer and others. The freezing happens playing the stream (m3u8) over Cloudfront via Windows (Firefox, Edge, Chrome), MacOS (Safari), iOS native player (I have tested with those). So why does MedaConvert cause this freezes in the output? The input is perfect.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: How did you "updating the aws-sdk version".  I'm getting a error that the rotate is not supported.  So I think I need to upload the aws-sdk. @user2761116

Comment: @zingle-dingle It was a long time ago. I downloaded the source I believe, and changed the version there, and uploaded the ZIP-ed source with changes

Comment: Update: I believe they updated the source files, maybe not needed to manually update the aws-sdk version

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: @zingle-dingle Acutally I don't remember any more.
I made a custom solution using ffmpeg on lambda.